# Change the column header in Runtime (Datagrid)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

Change the column header in Runtime (Datagrid)

Is there a way to do this?

How Change the background color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the header named in code, you can try to change the style of the header:

```
<DataGrid>
     <DataGrid.Columns>
           <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="m_yourColumn" Header="Header" />
      </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

```cs
Style newStyle = new System.Windows.Style() { TargetType=typeof(Control)};
newStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.BackgroundProperty,new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)));
m_yourColumn.HeaderStyle = yourNewStyle();
```

What I don't know, is which property to set. Maybe you have to change the HeaderTemplate before you can change the background. In my example I set Control.Background, but maybe this is not enough.

Comment: How Change the background color?

Comment: @H.B. You're right, I really should not answer questions today... I have changed my code and hope that it's now almost without errors :)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
var style = new Style();
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Border.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Red)); //Brush of your choice here
_myColumn.HeaderStyle = style; //Column referenced via x:Name
```